# Earth wrecked by disaster - Alien invasion at the end

Tags: story-identification, novel

A novel I read c1960, possibly the first of a trilogy or series, started with the discovery of a rock which the expert says came from 5000 feet down, but cannot explain how it got to the surface. He knows of no machine that could have extracted it, though speculating that the Russians might have such a device in the Urals.

The hero and heroine go underground to investigate the matter, but when they emerge  at the end they find civilisation destroyed by some force which they have inadvertantly released from within the earth. As they come out, they see alien spacecraft descending, pesumably to take over the ruined world, and the book concludes with them emerging to face "the forces of the unknown".

Does this ring any bells? It is probably 1950s but could be older.

Comment: 5000ft down isn't especially deep. It wouldn't make the top 26 working mines,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_deepest_mines let alone core drilling that was focused on simply getting as deep as possible.

Comment: @Valorum My take-aways from that list: 1) Holy heck, South Africa.  2) Only those damnfool Canadians will dig that deep for something other than gold.  3) South Africa!

Comment: You may well be right but I'm sure that is what the character said. I cannot vouch for the accuracy of the author's statements.